# Java Double.doubleToLongBits into C# BitConverter.ToDouble

Tags: java, c#, double

Can I convert a Java double to 8 bytes using [java.lang.Double.doubleToLongBits](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/lang/double_doubletolongbits.htm), write to network, then read those bits in C# using [BitConverter.ToDouble](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.bitconverter.todouble(v=vs.110).aspx)?

Given the C# docs make no mention of IEEE 754 but do talk about endianness, indicating platform dependence, I suspect not in the general case. What if I know both Java and C# processes are running on Intel X64 architecture? With Java on Linux, C# on Windows. Any details would be interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be possible, C# does use IEEE 754 doubles.  The only problem might be the endianness when transfering them over the network, so just choose the one your architecture is using and it should transfer correctly.

Note, if you use a `ByteBuffer`, you can select the desired endian easily.  Just use its `double` functions, no need to use `doubleToLongBits` -- that's just there in case you need the double representation to be converted to a long.

Comment: In fact, you have to use ByteBuffer, because Java operations are always big-endian, on all architectures, unless a ByteBuffer is assigned LITTLE_ENDIAN order.

Comment: @VGR The JVM itself uses the native byte ordering, however libraries to read and write binary default to big endian.